# grep and separate output into two columns

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following output that I have a grep'ed for

```
ltm pool www.cloud.com-Pool-80 
monitor http
ltm pool www.cloud.com-Pool-443
monitor https
ltm pool www.cloud.com-Pool-8080
monitor tcp
```

But would like the output to appear as follows .

```
ltm pool www.cloud.com-Pool-80 monitor http
ltm pool www.cloud.com-Pool-443  monitor https
ltm pool www.cloud.com-Pool-8080  monitor tcp
```

I have had good look through the man page for grep and egrep but there does not seem to be simple way to do this ?? Ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pipe the output from `grep` to an `awk`post-processor

```
grep .... | awk '{ORS=NR % 2? " ": "\n"; print}'
```

Depending on the complexity of the regular expression you might be able to combine the filtering and the post-processing into a single `awk` command

Alternately, a superb `paste` solution proposed by [don crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti)

```
grep ... |  paste -d ' ' - -
```

Comment: awk has regexp pattern matching built-in. you don't need grep here.  anywhere that you do `grep pattern | awk '{...}'` you can (and should) do `awk '/pattern/ {...}'`

Comment: @cas,what version of `awk` can handle the full power of perl-compatible regex that GNU `grep` can with `grep -P`?

Comment: `perl -a` :). more seriously, grep -P is merely a convenience....there's nothing grep can do with PCRE that it, or awk, can't also do with basic or extended regexp.

Comment: @cas, pcre grep can handle lookahead and lookbehind assertions among other things, I'm pretty sure these don't exist in BRE and ERE.  Not saying one can't get by without these for the most part but when one needs them, one really needs them

Comment: true. i'm guilty of `grep | awk` sometimes like most people but in most cases it's not necessary.  when it is, i'm likely to just write it in perl.